# How to redraw the Tmux client?

Tags: linux, shell, terminal, tmux

How can I redraw the Tmux client, when artifacts appear in the status line?

I have configured the following (right) status line:

```
set -g status-right "#[fg=green,bright]#{?client_prefix,#[reverse]<Prefix>#[noreverse],} | %a %d/%m/%y | %H:%M:%S |"
```

However, sometimes after activity, number(s) may appear after `%H:%M:%S |`, e.g. `%H:%M:%S |3`

I have attempted `refresh-client`, but it doesn't fix this issue. In contrast, `detach-client` followed by `tmux attach -tmain` resolves the issue.

System:

- Tmux 3.2a
- macOS 11.5.2

[image]

Comment: Does resizing the (GUI) window help?

Comment: "sometimes after activity" -- Have you identified an example activity that always causes (or is very likely to cause) the issue?

Comment: Does this work if you change your status right to `set -g status-right "#[fg=green,bright]#{?client_prefix,#[reverse],} | %a %d/%m/%y | %H:%M:%S |"`?